# Group by multiple values in mongodb with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I have this `query` and i want to `group by`  `{"$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d ", "date": "$first" }` and `"id13":"$samples.id13"`

```
mydb1.mongodbbuckethour.aggregate([

    {
        "$match": {
            "first": {"$gte": datetime.strptime("2010-01-01 00:05:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                          "$lte" :datetime.strptime("2020-12-31 23:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$samples" },
{
        "$match": {
            "first": {"$gte": datetime.strptime("2010-01-01 00:05:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                          "$lte" :datetime.strptime("2020-12-31 23:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
        }
    },

{
        "$group": {
            "_id": {"$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d ", "date": "$first" } ,"id13":"$samples.id13"}





        }
      },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "day":"$_id",

        }
    },
    {"$sort": {"day": -1}}
])
```

The `output` says:
`An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d ", date: "$first" }, id13: "samples.id13" }`
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error comes from the usage of `$dateToString`, since that is an expression for whose containing object you cannot specify any further object keys. What you probably wanted to do is assign the `$dateToString` expression to a dedicated field, `date` in this example:

```
{"$group": {
    "_id": {
        "date": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d ", "date": "$first"}},
        "id13": "$samples.id13"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello!!Thank you for your help!i think that it doesnt work.it says                                                                                                                                                                                               Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting.

Comment: That sounds like a follow-up issue. You can look into how to enable external sorting for a mongodb query to fix this, as your query appears to require to sort a large amount of data. If this is a recurring query you may also want to look into adding a proper index to avoid expensive sort operations

Comment: .i think the problem is in my project function..Now with the changes you told me i do :    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "day":"$date"

        }
    },
    {"$sort": {"date": -1}}